# OptaPlanner Collaboration with Anylogic

Tags: multi-objective-optimization

Is there a way that i can let Anylogic Collaborate with OptaPlanner?

I need to do both Simulation and Optimization for a logistic project.

Answer (score 4):

If you want o have OptaPlanner create schedules and then measure the quality (= the score) of each schedule through that Anylogic simulator, [take a look at the `EasyScoreCalculator` interface in the docs](https://www.optaplanner.org/docs/optaplanner/latest/score-calculation/score-calculation.html#easyJavaScoreCalculation). It's not incremental, so this approach won't scale well, but it does allow plugging in external score calculation easily.

Comment: i need to connect optaplanner to Anylogic to use some optimization models, i imported now the python communicator (Pypeline) jar file for Anylogic so now i can import python scripts to Anylogic.... I saw that there is an Optaplanner library in python (optapy).... I want to import it to Anylogic using the pypeline and apply Optaplanner models there, but tbh i dont know how efficient and applicable it is ....Also i need a documentation to apply it in case it could work

Comment: [Here are the python docs for that EasyScoreCalculator](https://www.optapy.org/docs/latest/score-calculation/score-calculation.html#easyPythonScoreCalculation). Hope that helps :)

Comment: Poster should identify their affiliation with OptaPlanner.

Comment: For answering a technical question about OptaPlanner? See my profile.